# Play framework, call static assets from action

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, assets

I'm trying to implement "guarded" assets in Play. By "guarded" I mean that a user first has to provide certain details (fill in a form) before being able to view the asset. I thought I could use Play's 'Asset' controller for serving the files. However, with the code snippet below, I keep getting a 404 error.

```
  def at(path: String, file: String) = Action { implicit request =>
    //do some internal logic to determine if file should be served
    controllers.Assets.at(path, file).apply(request) //serve the file <- always 404 error
  }
```

Is it possible to call Play's Asset.at controller method in an action?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the solution, play has to be notified of a new assets folder (that will be packaged with the application). Add this in Project/Build.scala

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
  playAssetsDirectories <+= baseDirectory / "name-of-new-assets-folder"  
)
```

Comment: This doesn't provide any information on how you "guarded" your resources

Comment: The first paragraph was to give context. The title, code snippet and actual question at the end ask something else

Comment: The answer still doesn't answer the question though. The question is "is it possible to call Play's Asset.at controller method in an action?" which it is, you simply call `root_.controllers.Assets.at` and then `apply` it to a request and you get back a `Result` that you can then return. so I don't see how updating the assetsDirectory has anything to do with calling a method on a built in controller